# Pytorch error "conv2d() received an invalid combination of arguments"

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

My model is very simple actually, but I cannot understand what is the error about. Is it about my data or my model.

here is the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-eed2a9a7f884> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 trainer=L.Trainer()#limit_train_batches özellikle ilk trainingde modelin çalışıp çalışmadığını görmek için oldukça faydalı olabilir.
----> 2 trainer.fit(unet_deneme, datamodule=data_module)

34 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    457                             weight, bias, self.stride,
    458                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
--> 459         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
    460                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    461 

TypeError: conv2d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (tuple, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, tuple, tuple, int), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!tuple of (Tensor, Tensor)!, !Parameter!, !Parameter!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, int)
 * (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, str padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!tuple of (Tensor, Tensor)!, !Parameter!, !Parameter!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, int)
```

and the code. Btw I am not sure whether if the problem is about my unet model or not. If you guyz say that my code is ok, I can load the data part too. I tried to change some parameters, and asked to chatgpt for reasonable answer, but still I couldnt figure out any solution

```
class double_conv(nn.Sequential):
  def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
    super(double_conv, self).__init__(
        nn.Conv2d(input_dim, output_dim, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(output_dim),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(output_dim, output_dim, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(output_dim),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
class encoder_block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_c, out_c):
        super().__init__()

        self.conv = double_conv(in_c, out_c)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2))

    def forward(self, inputs):
        x = self.conv(inputs)
        p = self.pool(x)

        return x, p
class decoder_block(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
    super().__init__()
    self.up=nn.ConvTranspose2d(input_dim, output_dim, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1)
    self.conv=double_conv(output_dim*2, output_dim)

    def forward(self, inputs, tasinan):
      x=self.up(inputs)
      x=torch.cat([inputs, tasinan],axis=1)
      x=self.conv(x)
      return x

class unet(L.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        """ Encoder """
        self.e1 = encoder_block(1, 64)
        self.e2 = encoder_block(64, 128)
        self.e3 = encoder_block(128, 256)
        self.e4 = encoder_block(256, 512)

        """ Bottleneck """
        self.b = double_conv(512, 1024)

        """ Decoder """
        self.d1 = decoder_block(1024, 512)
        self.d2 = decoder_block(512, 256)
        self.d3 = decoder_block(256, 128)
        self.d4 = decoder_block(128, 64)

        """ Output """
        self.output = nn.Conv2d(64, 1, kernel_size=1, padding=0)

  def forward(self, x):
    x1=self.e1(x)
    x2=self.e2(x1)
    x3=self.e3(x2)
    x4=self.e4(x3)

    x5=self.b(x4)

    x6=self.d1(x5)
    x7=self.d2(x6)
    x8=self.d3(x7)
    x9=self.d4(x8)

    x9=self.output(x9)

    return x9
  def training_step(self, batch, batch_number):
    
    x, y=batch
    y_pred=self.forward(x)
    loss=F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_pred, y)
    tensorboard_logs = {'train_loss': loss}
    
    return {'loss': loss, 'log': tensorboard_logs}

  def configure_optimizers(self):
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
    return optimizer

unet_deneme=unet()
```

Comment: The issue is with how you're inputing data into your trainer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.